# How to remove a large sim card from a Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: samsung, sim-card

Someone put a large size SIM card into the card slot of my Samsung Galaxy S8 without using the tray. How do I get it out?

Comment: I would start with a spiky tweezers if there is a little space to grab the card. If nothing works you could try to could try to adhere something (e.g. a paper-clip) to the SIM card with a very very small drop of superglue.

Comment: I tried with tweezers, but that didn't work. And I didn't feel like putting superglue into the phone's slot - knowing my track record, that wouldn't have ended well. So I ended up bringing it into a phone repair shop, where they were able to open it and remove the card intact. Oh well, lesson learned.